# Registering a Directshow Filter

Tags: c#, directshow

I would like to know what is the mechanism for registering a filter.

In my case, it's `= xvidvfw.dll.`
This is XVid Filter ("Xvid MPEG-4 Codec") and I want to know how to register in the client machine? is this possible?
I tried to use - `RegSvr32`, but it failed!

Moreover, is it necessary to run codecpack installation in the client machine?
Where do I find the above Filter? viz- in Win7 Codec, Win8 Codec etc.

Answer (score 3):

Regsvr32 does generic COM registration, which involves running DLL's registration code, which in turn not only registers COM classes, but also does registration of hosted DirectShow filters.

That is, regsvr32 is the registration that does it in full, there is nothing else. The registration might fail for reasons specific to DLL code (esp. bugs), in particular the typical reasons for failure include:

- attempt to register with missing static link dependency (or, C runtime dependency)
- attempt to register without elevating UAC privileges

Codec packs more often evil than not. You don't know what it drags into machine and how exactly it tweaks its defaults. It is always safer to install individual filter you need.

Comment: How to install an individual filter... in my case - Xvid MPEG-4 Codec. I also don't know where to get it from...?

Comment: `1` "regsvr32 is the registration that does it in full" (if you install it with installer - it does registration for you) `2` [xvid.org/Downloads](http://www.xvid.org/Downloads.15.0.html)